# jssor width and height in percentages

Tags: slider, jssor

The slides and captions and all elemetns of jssor slider take measuments in pixels. As a result the sliders look wierd on a bigger resolution screens. How do i mention heights and widhts of the jssor sliders in percentages?

Answer (score 1):

you can use $ScaleWidth(with) method to scale the slider to any size.

```
<script>
    //scale jssor slider to 70% width of parent container
    jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(parentWidth * 0.7);
</script>
```